# How to get menu as recursive array from drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How I retrieve the main menu and its sub menu items as a recursive array. Also how do I get the submenu for a particular node to show it in that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the menu and it's child links with something like the following, typically seen in a hook_preprocess_page() function:

```
$links = menu_tree_output(menu_tree_page_data(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu')));
```

In terms of displaying the 'submenu' on respective pages, I highly recommend using the [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block%20%22Menu%20Block%22%20module.) module.